# Broken Apache after upgrade from squeeze to wheezy

Tags: apache-http-server, debian-squeeze, arm, debian-wheezy

I have spent a good while searching and haven't been able to fix this problem.
I had a working chroot of Debian squeeze on my arm machine. I followed the guide to upgrading from squeeze to wheezy I required some functionality which wasn't available in squeeze.
The upgrade was pretty straightforward. 
After the upgrade I can't connect to any Apache sites. I have turned logging to debug and My log is full of the following.

```
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:34 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:34 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:35 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:35 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:35 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:35 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:35 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:35 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.4-11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:35 2013] [info] Server built: Oct 31 2012 00:17:58
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:35 2013] [debug] prefork.c(1023): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:36 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:37 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:37 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:38 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:38 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:38 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:38 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:39 2013] [info] server seems busy, (you may need to increase StartServers, or Min/MaxSpareServers), spawning 8 children, there are 3 idle,$
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:39 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:39 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:39 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:39 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:39 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:39 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
[Wed Jan 23 23:23:39 2013] [error] (38)Function not implemented: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
```

Ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the main Linux kernel is not compatible with wheezy as this is a 2.6.31 kernel ans wheezy requires a  2.6.32 or later. udev among other things fails to start (udev requires a kernel = 2.6.32 not started)

Comment: Can you throw a link in this answer to perhaps something you found on kernel.org or somewhere else that explains this in more details?